# The view app.views.MyWizard didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django

This is my views.py:

```
class OnlyNonLoggedInMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/page/")

class MyWizard(OnlyNonLoggedInMixin, SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/ok/")
```

Why I have this error and how to fix it?

```
The view app.views.MyWizard didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dispatch()` method doesn't return an `HttpResponse` object in case a user is not authenticated:

```
class OnlyNonLoggedInMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/page/")
        return super(OnlyNonLoggedInMixin, self).dispatch(
            self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have: `'MyWizard' object has no attribute 'session'`